# Selecting multiple items on a timeline in vis.js with one click

Tags: javascript, arrays, vis.js

I have created a timeline (with items) with vis.js library.Except from id, each item has also other attributes, such as content and className. 
What I am trying to do is click on an item and automatically highlight all the other items that have the same className with the one clicked.

Till now I have only managed to receive the id of the item clicked, but not other information such as the className. 
Is it possible to receive the className attribute? Is there a way that it can be done through vis.js? 
Thank you in advance

Comment: if you're asking about timeline, why `vis.js-network` tag? It is for the network module..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll try help. However, I'm still kinda new to vis.js timeline.

Basically I just filter and return the timeline's items for the first selected item and get it's className. I then query the timeline again asking it to return me all items with that className.

Finally, I use the setSelection method with my basket of ids to select and highlight the items in the timeline.

```
timeline.on('select', function (props) {

    // create empty array to hold ids of items with the same class name
    var sameClassNameIds = []

    // selected item/s ids given to you as an array on selection
    console.log(props.items)

    // define a variable which get and hold the selected item's object by filtering the timeline
    var selectedItem = items.get({
        filter: function (item) {
            //return id from timeline matching id in props.items
            return props.items.indexOf(item.id) !== -1;
        }
    });

    // here is the selected item's className
    var selectedClassName = selectedItem[0].className

    // retrieve all items with the above className
    var sameClassNameItems = items.get({
        filter: function (item) {
            //return items from timeline matching query
            return item.className === selectedClassName;
        }
    });

    // loop over retrieved array of items pushing each item id into an array
    sameClassNameItems.forEach(function (item) {
        sameClassNameIds.push(item.id)
    })

    // feed the setSelection method the array of ids you'd like it to select and highlight
    timeline.setSelection(sameClassNameIds)

});
```